# If Alex could not commit any sexual or violent act after watching that nasty stuff in a clockwork orange, how could he have jumped out a window?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-clockwork-orange

So in *A Clockwork Orange*, I am curious if Alex could not have committed acts of violence/sex any more after watching those tapes the scientists made him see it is proven after he tries to simply punch someone who is making fun of him in the red suit back at his house and when Dim and Pete find him they try to beat him up and kill him and he cannot possibly commit an act of violence even to defend himself; if that is the case, if the treatment actually worked, then  how could he have jumped out a two or three story window in an attempt to commit suicide? That's pretty violent, isn't it? I don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

You can rewatch the scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDkzbIIKDJU).

Alexandre was treated with the [Ludovico technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange_(novel)#Part_2:_The_Ludovico_Technique) in which the soundtrack was Beethoven's *9th Symphony*. So any violent situation makes him incredibly sick, you are correct here. An unintended consequence of that is Beethoven's music will also create this painful sickness.

At this moment, hearing the loud *9th Symphony* was the source of his pain, so this was an ultimate huge violence here. Jumping from the window was a lesser violence than the one he was enduring.

That's why his body, his muscles allowed him to commit this almost-lethal jump.